# How to position a sprite relative to a body

Tags: andengine

How do I position a `Sprite` and `Text` entities relative to the position of a  `Body` on the screen. I tried `body.getPosition().x` and this gives weird results.I think it may be a bounds issue, as I want only the area of the screen that is shown to be used in the calculations and not the entire map space that's available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the body position in PIXELTOMETER(PTM) ratio w.r.t physics world.So you have to multiply PTM ratio to the body to get the pixel values as follows

```
body.getPosition().x*PTM
```

Comment: Thanks for this bit of information, I am still pretty new to andengine. Is this explained further somewhere else, or just general knowledge? I am not sure what the PTM is.

Comment: actually PTM= 32 which we use basically for world. If you want to know more about this then go though physics tutorials.

Comment: Do you have a link for those tutorials handy?